# Generating and storing salt in the database when using crypt()

Tags: php, mysql, cryptography

What I used to do:

```
$salt = md5(time().rand(0,9999999).rand(0,100000));
$hashed_password = sha1($salt.$_REQUEST["newpassword"].sha1($salt));
$query = "update users set password=:hashed_password, salt=:salt where uid=:uid";
```

And then to check the password

```
if ($mysql_row["password"]==sha1($mysql_row["salt"].$_REQUEST["loginpassword"].sha1($mysql_row["salt"]))) loginsuccess = true;
```

Now I find out that this is an unsafe way to store passwords because `sha1()` is crap, so I decided to use [crypt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). I'm not using [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) because I sometimes have to move a site to another server that has a different (sometimes older) PHP and I want the hashes/passwords generated on later PHP versions to still work on servers with the earlier PHP versions.

So `crypt()` says I can do something like

```
$salt = md5(time().rand(0,9999999).rand(0,100000));
$hashed_password = crypt($_REQUEST["newpassword"],$salt); 
$query = "update users set password:hashed_password where uid=:uid"; // doesn't save salt
```

and then to check the password:

```
if (crypt($_REQUEST["loginpassword"], $mysql_row["password"]) == $mysql_row["password"]) $loginsuccess = true;
```

So my questions are:

1. Do I really not have to store the salt anywhere when using `crypt()`? Is `crypt($something,$somethingelse)==$somethingelse` always true when $something==$somethingelse ? (now I realize I could've just started with this question)
2. Am I right that hashes generated with the [compatibility pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) on newer PHP versions may not be the same as those generated on older PHP versions, so in effect making generated passwords incompatible between different versions of PHP? If so, why is it called a "compatibility" pack?

I realize I could test most of this, but when it comes to security I'd rather have an expert opinion.

Comment: Use mt_rand. Rand and mt_rand are both pseudo-random, if you want full proof salt generator include an integer from random.org. It uses atmospheric noise. You can use cURL to collect the digit.

Comment: So, to crack one user's password, the attacker would have to know the exact second the password was hashed, guess two randomly generated numbers, reverse a md5 hash and then reverse whatever crypt() did, and this is still unsafe? You'd think the attacker would just go to the user's house and beat the password out of him. Oh well, mt_rand() it is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it can vary from server to server; it depends on the available algorithms. `password_hash` allows you to specify the algorithm.
2. See 1. `password_hash` is compatible with `crypt`.

---

There is one more problem with your code:

Your salt generation is not random enough. `rand` is not very good. `mt_rand` is slightly better, `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is good, `password_hash` is recommended (but you know this).

Comment: OK, but what when I have to move a site that was on PHP 5.5+ to a server that's on an earlier PHP version? Will the users still be able to log in?

Comment: That depends on whether `crypt` decides to the use same algorithm. If you're upgrading to a server that supports `password_hash` then you can convert old passwords to a new chosen algorithm. But downgrading is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to go with the password_hash() after all. I was first put off reading that it doesn't work on PHP < 5.3.7 but it works on every hosting server I tried (even on 5.2.17) and it really is convenient. Here's hoping it doesn't have any vulnerabilities.